# Erro de socket somente no Android 7

Tags: java, android, socket

Esse problema ocorre apenas no Android 7!

Em outras versões o funcionamento é perfeito. E realizando os testes em um S8 com a troca inteligente de rede, pelos relatos de um amigo, também está funcionando como deveria.

O meu é um G5 Plus e não possui maneira de desligar a troca inteligente de rede.

Em determinados momentos ele conecta mas na maior parte das vezes não e o erro retornado em IOException é Network is unreachable.

O pedaço do código onde o corre o erro:

```
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();

    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, SERVERPORT), 20000); //<- aqui gera o erro
        main.socket = clientSocket;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Artur",e1.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Artur","Erro:"+e1.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Você já viu se existe algum watch para detectar quando ocorre uma mudança de rede? Tente colocar o socket como global e na troca de rede você fecha e abre a conexão novamente.

Comment: Vou tentar. Mas acho que já resolvi. Não existe nenhum problema no código. É o Android que desconecta sozinho e cai na rede celular. Ele verifica que meu aparelho não possui internet e procura a conexão em outro lugar. Em outros telefones basta desligar a opção de troca inteligente de rede. Mas no Moto G5 Plus não existe essa opção. Então nele nunca vai funcionar mas não é por culpa do programa.

Comment: Consegui usando essa solução: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329775/using-a-wifi-without-internet-connection/46165010#46165010